# Jquery Addclass isn't working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, addclass

I have this code and it doesn't work; I have no idea why. I tried it in all browsers (IE, chrome, firefox).  I suppose that the system must add the class and I tried the console of chrome to see the DOM. I saw the added class but no change in chrome or other browsers.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      #boton
      {
        width:200px;
        height:30px;
        border:1px solid;
        background-color:#cccccc;
      }


    </style>

    <style>
      .botoncla
      {
        background-color:#FF0000;
      }
    </style>


    <script>



    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#boton").hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("botoncla");
      }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("botoncla");
     });
    });

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
       <div id="boton">Hello</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Can someone test this?  It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Create and http://jsFiddle.net, then maybe you get some help.

Comment: The problem is your background-color is conflicting. The added class isn't overwriting the standard class' background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery code is working but your CSS does not work because the `background-color` of `.botoncla` does not overite `background-color` of `#boton`.

Try with this :

```
.botoncla
{
    background-color:#FF0000 !important;
}
```

**EDIT**

However in your case, `!important` is a hack ... Maybe you should use `.animate()` instead :

```
$(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "FF0000" }, "slow");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, AnaelFavre!
`.animate()` is one option. He could also use `.css()`, in case he doesn't actually want it to animate.

Comment: and always need use improtant for work this , i see other examples and no use important , thank´s for your answer

Comment: I want use addclass for animate , if i use css i can´t animate color change , i can put time for change color use addclass and create effect  $(this).addClass("botoncla",2000); for example

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
#boton.botoncla {
background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

Comment: Yes perfect i don´t think in that , perfect

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things wrong here. First of all, you include jQuery two times, and jQuery UI (which is not used). The two jQuery versions are also different, as `latest` refers to the `1.7.2` build. Remove one of them (probably v1.4).

The reason why it doesn't apply the styling from `.botoncla`, is because an ID always have higher specificity than a class, meaning the styling from `#boton` is considered more important. You could either add an `!important` to the declaration, or better yet, make it more specific like so: `#boton.botoncla`

See my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/rvUtT/

Comment: Thank´s for your help i don´t think in that , i try create animation for rollover with effects , and now working , regards